# Matplotlib, Setting position of chart in image

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'm making a tool to automate a couple of graphs using Matplotlib, for each problem I encountered, usually after some research I end-up finding a solution, but here I think I'm stuck.

1 - What I want is to have, in the generated png file, a kind of an Offset before the graph starts on the left, where I can insert some text objects. How can that be done ?

2 - I also want to be able to insert text beneath the graph, so it would be useful.

Mainly I want to be able to define the position of the plot in the image file, Here is an example of what I currently [have](http://s15.postimg.org/ck05lewzv/el_fichier.png), and of what [I want](http://s24.postimg.org/fnwrfhbt1/Screen_Shot_2014_11_07_at_12_42_55_PM.png).

EDIT :

```
def plot_bar():


  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(600/96, 360/96), dpi = 96)


# Setting the padding between the ticks' labels and the axes
  mpl.rcParams['xtick.major.pad']='10'

  ax = plt.gca()

  ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
  ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
  ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
  ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)


  ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

  mpl.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'white'
  mpl.rcParams["figure.facecolor"]= 'white'
  mpl.rcParams["savefig.facecolor"]= 'white'
  Values1 = ( 10 , 25 , 30 , 40 )
  Values2 = ( 40 , 3 , 10 , 6 )

  N = 4

  ind = np.arange(N)

  width = 0.7
p1 = plt.bar(ind, Values1, width, color='#00A79A', ec='#00A79A')
  p2 = plt.bar(ind, Values2, width, color='#8FDCD6', bottom = Values1, ec='#8FDCD6')


  plt.xticks(ind+width/2., ('Fuel\n\n dollars \n\n dollars', 'Tires', 'Roadcalls', 'Maintenance') )
  plt.yticks(np.arange(0,81,10))

  # Removing Tick lines from axes
  for tic in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tic.tick1On = tic.tick2On = False

  for tic in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tic.tick1On = tic.tick2On = False
  plt.savefig("fichier.png")
```

Comment: Can you give us the code you're using to form the figure?

Comment: Of course, I'll add it.

Comment: Can you please let us know if the solution provided works for you? If not, we can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_adjust.html) to add spacing. [`tight_layout`](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html) will also extend your box to fit the text that was missing from the plot before ("dollars").

As for the rest of the plot, it should be reasonably easy to add labels. For example, the `for` loop below adds the totals on top of each bar (similar to [this demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)).

```
for bar in p2:
    height = bar.get_height() + p1[bar.get_x()].get_height()
    ax.text(bar.get_x()+bar.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height),
            ha='center', va='bottom')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3, bottom=0.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `subplots_adjust` figure method:

```
fig.subplots_adjust( left=0.25, bottom=0.25 )
```